# cpp: "-c" is not a valid option to the preprocessor

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, build-automation

I'm trying to build a package on a RedHat system.  First, I ran ./configure CXX=cpp, because /usr/bin/cpp is the C++ compiler on that system.  But when I run make, it dumps:

cpp: "-c" is not a valid option to the preprocessor

When I do a Google search, I found a number of complaints, but no solutions.  Anyone else encounter this?

Answer (score 15):

`cpp` is the C preprocessor; perhaps you mean `cc` (the C compiler) or `gcc` (for GNU C compiler) or `g++` (for the GNU C++ compiler)?

Answer (score 9):

`cpp` is the preprocessor, try `c++`  instead.

Answer (score 1):

I had to install the cpp-g++ package.  I'm not used to Redhat systems, and hadn't built a C++ program in quite a while, hence my confusion.

Thanks to all for your generous responses.

Answer (score 0):

you probably are looking for g++ (GNU C++ Compiler) as cpp is the C preprocessor.

g++ is a special invocation of gcc in that it automatically includes a couple of directories needed for gcc's c++ runtime into the library search path.